# PHP rename error on Centos although custom upload tmp dir is defined

Tags: php, permissions

I get the follow error below. I'm not sure why now since I changed the temp directory location. By default it uses /tmp - I didn't want to mess with this folder since the entire centos os relies on that folder -- just incase i didn't touch it or changed its permission or ownership.

```
rename(/var/www/html/doc-generate/tmp/WO3Yfe,Mission Announcement Sheet - BB&T76.docx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/doc-generate/wwwroot/phpword/src/PhpWord/Template.php on line 338
```

So I created a tmp directory in this folder `/var/www/html/doc-generate/tmp/`

I did a:

```
[root@project-open-v40 doc-generate]# ps aux | grep "apache" 
apache   14445  0.0  0.3  31336  6484 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14446  0.0  0.2  31336  5236 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14447  0.0  0.2  31336  5236 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14448  0.0  0.2  30996  3940 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14449  0.0  0.2  30996  3940 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14450  0.0  0.2  30996  3940 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14451  0.0  0.2  30996  3940 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14452  0.0  0.2  30996  3940 ?        S    12:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     17542  0.0  0.0   4356   732 pts/1    S+   13:34   0:00 grep apache
```

Turns out apache is the httpd owner. But the scrip that's being executed is:

```
exec php /var/www/html/doc-generate/wwwroot/phpword/samples/MissionAnnouncementSheet.php
```

Is apache is owner when you execute php from command line?

I also did a 777 on the tmp upload fodler. The owner of the file that's being crated /var/www/html/doc-generate/tmp/WO3Yfe is projop so I changed the chown projop:projop to /var/www/html/doc-generate/tmp/ still throwing Permission error. Any Clues anyone?

Comment: `whoami` from the command line if you're executing the PHP file by hand.

Comment: no, the command line is run as whatever user YOU are logged into. the only time a php script would be executed as `apache` is if it's running UNDER apache (e.g. an http request), or you've suid'd the script and/or sudo'd over to the apache user.

Comment: yeah but when the server runs it I belive it's using the user projop and I've changed the temp folder location folder ownership to chown projop:projop /folder/ no luck, i still get Permission Denied error---

Comment: I did a 777 and 7777 and 1777 chmod on the folder still no luck.

Comment: ERROR: 13:46:40 Create new PhpWord object 13:46:40 Write to Word2007 format Warning: rename(/var/www/html/doc-generate/tmp/jcyTzA,Mission Announcement Sheet - BB&T76.docx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/doc-generate/wwwroot/phpword/src/PhpWord/Template.php on line 338 Warning: rename(Mission Announcement Sheet - BB&T76.docx,/media/gainshared/BB&T/76 Open/Agreement.Invoice/Mission Announcement Sheet - BB&T76.docx): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/doc-generate/wwwroot/phpword/samples/MissionAnnouncementSheet.php on line 93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your apache config for the value:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir
```

Probably you will find something like ":/tmp/:" in the string.
Add your new directory there.

Comment: Thank you @hellcode - you saved me hours worth of hair pulling and head banging against my desk.